# Voltage divider or zener clamp when coupling a comparator output signal to a DAQ?

Tags: voltage-divider, zener, comparator

[image]

As shown in above figures above, a comparator is outputting 16V pulse signal when it is ON.

For some reason I want to lower this voltage around 8V pulse.
In Config 1, it is coupled to a voltage divider. In Config 2, it is coupled to a zener clamp. 
This final 8V pulses will then be coupled to a DAQ which will count the pulses. 
The reason of stepping down the voltage is that the DAQ has 10V input limit.
The DAQ has input impedance 100Gohm.

I can use both Config 1 and 2. But is there an advantage of one configuration to another? 
Which one would you use and is more convenient?

Comment: what compartor?

Comment: general comparator or schmitt trigger.

Comment: so nothing at all like an ordinary comparator like LM319 then?

Comment: yes it doesnt matter, imagine a schmitt trigger or compa ator has 16V 0V pulse train output. The rest is the question. Coupling config to the DAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either choice will work.

Configuration 1 is cheaper, both in component costs and PCB area, so I'd probably go with that.

If the pulses are very narrow, the transient response of configuration 1 is also better, since a zener will have greater stray capacitance, but that's likely not a concern, since really narrow pulses should probably have some sort of detection circuitry.

Answer (score 2):

resistors are better behaved than zeners at low power (and also cheaper) 
go with the resistive divider.